# Installing Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-xp

I've 2 hard disks. I've installed Ubuntu on the **HDA(0)**, but there are plenty of spaces. But On the **HDA(0)** there is only one partition.

My question
How can I edit / create another partition on **HDA(0)** to install Windows XP on the 2nd partition ?
How can I install Windows XP on **HDA(1)** and still be able to boot in Windows XP or Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

First you should use a live system to partition the disk with Gparted (it is included in Ubuntu live) and create a NTFS partition.
Remember to reserve the first partition to Windows (some versions of it don't recognize NTFS partitions if there's something else before them).

Then you should install Windows in that partition and, in the end, you have to recover GRUB, as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: How to create the first partition, as i think Ubuntu is using 1st partition.

Comment: Gparted lets you move and re-size partitions as well as create partitions. So, you re-size the first partition so that there is unallocated space in front of it. You then create the new partition out of the unallocated space. But I must tell you that the received wisdom is to install Windows first and then install Linux and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted to shrink partitions.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php

After you installed windows, you can use EasyBCD to edit the Windows boot manager for that it gives you the option to load Linux.
http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

I know it works, I have done it once.
If you put grub in the MBR, then you will get into trouble when some settings change (e.g. the kernel renames the /dev/sda1 to /dev/hda1 etc., and then it will boot neither Windows nor Linux.

I don't know whether you still need to move grub from the MBR to to /dev/hda1 or wherever your primary Linux partition is, but I think it works without that as well.

I would install a Windows driver that enables windows to read the ext3/4 fs.
I don't know whether something for ext4 exsts already, but ext3 was definitely supported, in order to access data on the Linux partition on Windows.